# Modifying image metadata without compressing it

Tags: objective-c, macos, metadata, core-media

Here is my code.

```
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef) data, NULL);
CFStringRef imageType = CGImageSourceGetType(source);
NSMutableData *resultData = [NSMutableData alloc];
CFDictionaryRef tempp= CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
CGImageDestinationRef imgDest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge `CFMutableDataRef)(resultData), imageType, 1,  (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dictionary);`
```

Now their is 2 method to write back image.

-> This method is compressing the size of image but writing metadata *perfectly*.

```
CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(imgDest, source, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dictionary);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(imgDest);
[resultData writeToFile:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/Users/jamil/Desktop/19nov/DSC_3170a.jpg"].path atomically:YES];
```

-> The other is not compressing image but is not writing metadata.

```
CGImageDestinationCopyImageSource(imgDest, source, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dictionary, NULL);
[resultData writeToFile:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/Users/jamil/Desktop/19nov/DSC_3170a.jpg"].path atomically:YES];
```

The `dictionary` is good formatted and also include the `kCGImageDestinationMergeMetadata` and `kCGImageDestinationMetadata`.